# SwiftUI - navigationBarBackButton

Tags: navigationbar, swiftui

1. How can I change `navigationBarBackButton` color in `SwiftUI`? (by
   default it's blue)
2. How can I change `navigationBarBackButton` text in `SwiftUI`?

This is my code (an example):

```swift
struct ExercisesList : View {
    var exercises : [Exercise]
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List(self.exercises.identified(by: \.number)) {exercise in
                NavigationLink(destination: ExerciseDetailView(exercise: exercise)) {
                    ExerciseRow(exercisE: exercise)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Exercises"))

        }
    }
}
```

By default, the `navigationBarBackButton` in "ExerciseDetailView" has a text of *Exercise* and color of *blue*.

My question is how can I manipulate these two?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: @mumu example code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Hope it will help. In this way, you can use custom UIColor also.

```
struct ExercisesList : View {
    var exercises : [Exercise]

    var body: some View {

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red

        return  NavigationView {
            List(self.exercises.identified(by: \.number)) { exercise in
                NavigationLink(destination: ExerciseDetailView(exercise: exercise)) {
                    ExerciseRow(exercisE: exercise)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Exercises"))


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, No direct methods are available for that(XCode 11 beta 3).
However You can use UINavigationBar method for that,

see below code :

```swift
 struct ExercisesList : View {
     var exercises : [Exercise]

     init() {
       //navigationBarBackButton color will change//
         UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .purple
       // you can also set backgroundColor//
         UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
     }

     var body: some View {

         NavigationView {
             List(self.exercises.identified(by: \.number)) {exercise in
                 NavigationLink(destination: ExerciseDetailView(exercise: exercise)) {
                     ExerciseRow(exercisE: exercise)
                 }
             }
             .navigationBarTitle(Text("Exercises"))
         }
     }
 }
```